# HLSL: Keep Getting An Oval When I Want a Circle! (Pixel Shader)

Tags: 2d, shader, pixel, geometry, hlsl

I'm trying to tint a circle around the player in my 2D side scroller but I keep getting an oval!  Here's the part of the code I'm using that matters:

```
    if(length(abs(coords - playerCoords)) < .1)
    {
        color = color *float4(1,0,1,1);
    }

  return color;
```

My screen size is 1280 wide x 720 tall.  I know that this is the reason for the distortion, but I don't know enough about my issue in order to come up with or find a solution.  Can someone explain to me how to compensate for the screen stretch?

Thanks!

-ATD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiply the "abs()" term by "float2((720./1280.),1.0)" -- or whatever your y/x aspect ration might be

The coords you are using are normalized in 0-1 space, so just correct them

Comment: BTW, the abs() isn't needed -- length() is always positive.    It is true that for all the GPUs I know, abs is a storage modifier so it's essentially free, but: it's not required here.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  Don't know why I put that in there.  I even knew that.